# unexpected keyword argument in simple Python code, why?

Tags: python, keyword-argument, marc

I'm trying to use the pymarc MARCReader library class.  My python code is choking at the line:

```
reader = MARCReader(file(input), to_unicode=True)
```

with the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_bib.py", line 10, in <module>
    reader = MARCReader(file(input), to_unicode=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'to_unicode'
```

From the source code for pymarc 3.0.1 I have copied the constructor syntax below:

```
class MARCReader(Reader):
<snip>
    def __init__(self, marc_target, to_unicode=True, force_utf8=False,
            hide_utf8_warnings=False, utf8_handling='strict'):
    <snip>
```

It seems to me that my code is correct.  I guess I don't understand keyword arguments well enough because I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: The code you've provided shouldn't generate the error you're seeing.  Double-check for typos, capitalization, etc?

Comment: You might want to also make sure that you're on the same version as the source you're looking at. Calling `help` on `MARCReader` might also be useful for checking the documentation.

Comment: ... and `print(pymarc.__file__)` to make sure you are importing what you think you are.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I wasn't aware of ".__file__"  I called it and it turns out I was using an old version of pymarc while I thought I was using the newer version.